# Define a neural network with PyTorch to train images with labels

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, pytorch

I have a 3 folders (train, validation and test) where the folder contains 1000, 100 and 100 images respectively with sizes 128x128 and a labels.txt file which contains the image name, center points (as x,y) and radius of the circles for all images in "images" directory. Here are the first few examples of the details in the labels.txt file:

```
0000,   0.68 ,   0.61 ,   0.24 
0001,   0.7  ,   0.33 ,   0.26 
0002,   0.52 ,   0.61 ,   0.22 
0003,   0.5  ,   0.49 ,   0.46 
0004,   0.43 ,   0.43 ,   0.36 
0005,   0.36 ,   0.38 ,   0.19 
0006,   0.4  ,   0.61 ,   0.3  
0007,   0.81 ,   0.5  ,   0.15 
0008,   0.7  ,   0.36 ,   0.26 
0009,   0.29 ,   0.56 ,   0.2
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbUEv.png) is an example of how the image looks like (First training image in the training dataset).

The image is fed into a neural network, whose outputs are the center and radius of the circle within the image (the image contains a rectangle, triangle and a circle). The domain considered is "[0,1]x[0,1] "box". The goal is to paint the circle. The images are RGB so therefore I do know that the shape of the image read is (3,128,128). I have created a dataset class and a data loader by doing some research, but as I am new to pytorch I am unsure of how to define the neural network. The code is as follows:

**Dataset class**

```
class ShapesDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, dataset_dir):
        """
        Initializing dataset by generating a dicitonary of labels, where an image file name is the key 
        and its labels are the contents of that entry in the dictionary. Images are not loaded. This way it
        is possible to iterate over arbitrarily large datasets (limited by labels dicitonary fitting 
        in memory, which is not a problem in practice)

        Args:
            dataset_dir : path to directory with images and labels. In this directory we expect to find
                          a directory called "images" containing the input images, and a file called 
                          "labels.txt" containing desired labels (coefficients)
        """

        self.dataset_dir = dataset_dir
        self.labels_dict = self.gen_labels_dict()
        self.images_keys = list(self.labels_dict)  # getting the keys of the dictionary as list
        self.images_keys.sort()                    # sorting so as to have in alphabetical order 

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels_dict)

    def __getitem__(self, index):    
        """
        This funtion makes it possible to iterate over the ShapesDataset
        Args:
            index: running index of images

        Returns:
            sample: a dicitionary with three entries:
                    1. 'image'  contains the image
                    2. 'labels' contains labels (coeffs) corresponding to image
                    3. 'fname'  contains name of file (image_key) - may be useful for debugging
        """
        image_key = self.images_keys[index]     # recall - key is the file name of the corresponding image
        image = np.array(Image.open(image_key)) # image has shape: (128, 128, 3)
        image = image/255.0                     # simple normalization - just to maintain small numbers
        image = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))  # network needs RGB channels to be first index
        labels = self.labels_dict[image_key]
        sample = {'image': image, 'labels': labels, 'fname':image_key}

        return sample


    def gen_labels_dict(self):
        """
        This fucntion generates a dictionary of labels

        Returns:
            labels_dict: the key is image file name and the value is the corresponding 
            array of labels  
        """

        labels_fname = self.dataset_dir + "/labels.txt"
        labels_dict = {}
        with open(labels_fname, "r") as inp:
            for line in inp:
                line = line.split('\n')[0]                                      # remove '\n' from end of line 
                line = line.split(',')
                key  = self.dataset_dir + '/images/' + line[0].strip() + ".png" # image file name is the key
                del line[0]

                list_from_line = [float(item) for item in line]
                labels_dict[key] = np.asarray(list_from_line, dtype=np.float32)

        return labels_dict
```

**Data loader**

```
train_dir      = "./train/"
validation_dir = "./validation/"
test_dir       = "./test/"


train_dataset = ShapesDataset(train_dir)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, 
                          batch_size=32,
                          shuffle=True)



validation_dataset = ShapesDataset(validation_dir)

validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, 
                               batch_size=1,
                               shuffle=False)



test_dataset = ShapesDataset(test_dir)

test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, 
                          batch_size=1,
                          shuffle=False)


print("train loader examples     :", len(train_dataset)) 
print("validation loader examples:", len(validation_dataset))
print("test loader examples      :", len(test_dataset))

#Output:
#train loader examples     : 1000
#validation loader examples: 100
#test loader examples      : 100
```

**And finally the definition of the neural network:**

**EDIT: Definition of NN **

```
class CircleNet(nn.Module):    # nn.Module is parent class  
    #Not sure if I am on the right track.
    def __init__(self):
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # We'll apply max pooling with a kernel size of 2
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

        # A second convolutional layer takes 12 input channels, and generates 12 outputs
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # A third convolutional layer takes 12 inputs and generates 24 outputs
       self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=24, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # A drop layer deletes 20% of the features to help prevent overfitting
        self.drop = nn.Dropout2d(p=0.2)

        # Our 128x128 image tensors will be pooled twice with a kernel size of 2. 128/2/2 is 32.
        # So our feature tensors are now 32 x 32, and we've generated 24 of them, so the array is 32x32x24
        # We need to flatten these and feed them to a fully-connected layer
        # to map them to  the probability for each class
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=32 * 32 * 24, out_features=num_classes) 

    #I am struggling to move forward from here            
    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Feed forward through network
        Args:
            x - input to the network

        Returns "out", which is the network's output
        """
        # Use a relu activation function after convolution 1 and pool
        x = F.relu(self.pool(self.conv1(x)))

        # Use a relu activation function after convolution 2 and pool
        x = F.relu(self.pool(self.conv2(x)))

        # Select some features to drop after the 3rd convolution to prevent overfitting
        x = F.relu(self.drop(self.conv3(x)))

        # Only drop the features if this is a training pass
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)

        # Flatten
        x = x.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 24)
        # Feed to fully-connected layer to predict class
        x = self.fc(x)
        # Return class probabilities via a softmax function 

        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Comment: In your forward method, you should at least feed the output from fc1 into fc2, from fc2 into fc3 etc. (just rename out to x) -- the doc string of nn.Module should give an example.

Comment: Thank you. I shall do that, but from the looks of it, based on the description, is my def __init__ (self) function right at least?

Comment: I don't think a linear stack can find a circle on an image, but I would be interested in hearing back if you're successful. I'd just assume it won't work, because linear layers don't see associations between neighboring pixels. That is what a CNN is better at doing. You should search how image nets find objects inside images. That's a big topic. Also, you need to pass `out` to the next layer in your `forward`, and you're missing an activation function like `ReLU`.

Comment: @Reactgular Thank you for your feedback, I have updated my NN definition after some extra research, hopefully it on the right track now.